# Sql query result using Group By Clause without including timestamp in date field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table as below which has records like, there are many records for a same client but their EffectiveDate and RunDate may be same or different. EffectiveDate and RunDate may also includes TimeStamp like 2014-02-09 14:15:30.000 and timestamp may be different for the same date.

```
ID  Client        EffectiveDate                 RunDate         
1   abc      01-01-2014 14:15:30.000    09-02-2014 14:15:30.000        
2   abc      02-01-2014 14:15:30.000    10-01-2014 14:15:30.000       
3   abc      02-01-2014 15:19:30.000    09-01-2014 15:19:30.000          
4   abc      03-01-2014 14:15:30.000    10-01-2014 14:15:30.000            
5   abc      03-01-2014 15:20:30.000    09-01-2014 15:20:30.000           
6   abc      02-01-2014 14:15:30.000    10-01-2014 14:15:30.000          
7   abc      04-01-2014 14:30:30.000    10-01-2014 14:30:30.000           
8   abc      04-01-2014 17:15:30.000    10-01-2014 17:15:30.000
```

I need a sql query which results like for same EffectiveDate it will count the number of records for that client regardless of EffectiveDate's Timestamp and RunDate (including its Timestamp). I need results like

```
 ID  Client      EffectiveDate   Number Of Records    
 1   abc          01-01-2014            1
 2   abc          02-01-2014            3
 4   abc          03-01-2014            2
 7   abc          04-01-2014            2
```

I know it may be possible using Group By in sql query But if there is timestamp in date then i am not able to get the desired result.

Comment: sorry i just forgot to add RunDate in result part... it should be also in result but if EffectiveDate is same and RunDate is different it'll not treat those record differently .. and used same above logic

Comment: Addyour expected result in question

Comment: I just updated query after you expect RunDate in result. Just try it and update your status.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below query to obtain the result:

```
    SELECT ID, Client, EffectiveDate, RunDate
    FROM 
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.Client, B.EffectiveDate, 
                B.NumberOfRecords ORDER BY A.ID) AS RowNum, 
                 A.ID, A.Client, B.EffectiveDate, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.RunDate ,105) 
                AS RunDate, B.NumberOfRecords
         FROM #Temp A 
         INNER JOIN (SELECT Client, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),EffectiveDate ,105) AS 
                          EffectiveDate, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfRecords
                     FROM #Temp
                      GROUP BY Client, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),EffectiveDate ,105)) B 
         ON A.Client = B.Client AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.EffectiveDate ,105) = 
            B.EffectiveDate) AS C
    WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `convert datetime to date` to remove the `timestamp` in `group by`

```
select  Client,convert(date,EffectiveDate), count(1) [Number Of Records]
from tablename 
group by Client,convert(date,EffectiveDate)
```

If you want result with Id then try this(untested).

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER(partition BY CONVERT(DATE, EffectiveDate) ORDER BY id) rn,*
         FROM   tablename)
SELECT a.ID,
       a.Client,
       a.EffectiveDate,
       b.[Number Of Records]
FROM   cte a
       JOIN(SELECT Client,
                   CONVERT(DATE, EffectiveDate) EffectiveDate,
                   Count(1)                     [Number Of Records]
            FROM   tablename
            GROUP  BY Client,
                      CONVERT(DATE, EffectiveDate)) b
         ON CONVERT(DATE, a.EffectiveDate) = b.EffectiveDate 
where rn =1
```

Answer (score 0):

select date part like this

```
select convert(varchar,getdate(),105)
```

also group by with the same

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(id) id,client,trunc(effectivedate) effectivedate,
min(trunc(rundate)) rundate,
count(client) no_of_records 
from tempd
group by client,trunc(effectivedate)
order by 1
```

You can try this one its working fine and fast in oracle sql, for rundate, depends on you which one you want to keep minimum or maximum one;in this query i kept it minimum if you want maximum then put max instead of min and you will get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query:

```
SELECT Min(ID) AS ID, 
    Client, 
    CONVERT(DATE,EffectiveDate) AS EffectiveDate, 
    MIN(RunDate) AS RunDate, 
    COUNT(*) AS [Number Of Records]
FROM ClientTableName
GROUP BY Client, CONVERT(Date,EffectiveDate)
```

NOTE: The only difference is the date format returned. which can be easily changed to required format